# Footer on all pages including Abstract but header on all pages except 1st page?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using `documentclass{report}`. I want footer on all pages including Abstract but header on all pages except 1st page of each chapter

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, margin=0.5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{\Images}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{L}{List of Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Abbreviations}{}}%
]}

\graphicspath{{D10/}{D15/}}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure} [H]
\includegraphics [width=20.9cm, height=29.65cm] {TU}
\end{figure}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{"arrows", "automata", "backgrounds", "calendar", "chains", "matrix", "mindmap", "patterns", "petri", "shadows", "shapes.geometric", "shapes.misc", "spy", "trees"}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\chaptername}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{Thesis}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Master of Science} 

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in}

\begin{titlepage}


\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\justify

\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\cfoot{}

\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\textheight = 674pt
\textwidth = 440pt
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{}
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\subfile{nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\newgeometry{width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=0.5in}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\textheight = 674pt
\textwidth = 440pt
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\chapter{Problem Statement}
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
\subfile{appendices}
\end{appendices}
\clearpage

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}


\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.se

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning of the document (e.g. just before the \begin{document}):

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

This says that the `plain` pagestyle is the same as the `fancy` pagestyle.

Then just before the first chapter:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% copy pagestyle fancy
     \fancyhead[]{}% but remove all header fields
     \renewcommand{\headrule}{}}% and remove the headrule
```